# M.Map sudden expected type error

Tags: haskell, hakyll, overloaded-strings, unordered-containers

Everything was working great up until about a month or so ago...

Suddenly I'm getting

```
 berkson.github.io/source/blog.hs: 333, 42
 • Couldn't match type ‘unordered-containers-0.2.7.1:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                          text-1.2.2.1:Data.Text.Internal.Text
                          aeson-0.11.2.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value’
                  with ‘M.Map [Char] [Char]’
   Expected type: M.Map [Char] [Char]
     Actual type: Metadata
 • In the first argument of ‘(M.!)’, namely ‘md’
   In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(md M.! "author")’
   In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(md M.! "author") ++ "/"’
```

From the code:

```
 directorizeDateAndAuthor :: Routes
 directorizeDateAndAuthor = metadataRoute $ \md ->
     gsubRoute "/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-" $ \s ->
         replaceAll "-" (const "/") s ++ (md M.! "author") ++ "/"
```

I was wondering if you'd mind helping me decipher what exactly it's telling me?  I get that there's some type  of syntax error on my end, but I don't understand what changed and why it's not compiling like it used to?

Ref: https://github.com/berkson/berkson.github.io/blob/source/source/blog.hs#L330

Comment: My guess is that you upgraded the package that defines `Metadata`, and that package changed from defining it to be in terms of `Map` to `HashMap`.  You need to update your usages of this type to use e.g. `HashMap.!` instead of `M.!`.  Or you could just change your cabal file to depend on an older version of the package.

Comment: In hakyll 4.8 `Metadata` type changed from `Map` to `Aeson.Object` (see [release announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hakyll/M3SNUkH2zsQ))

Comment: @JanTojnar gah! Thank you for telling me, but now I'm even more lost!  I thought it'd be just a drop in replacement for itself but instead of the error before I'm getting:

`Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Value’`

Instead! >_< Haskell is so confusing to me still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before hakyll 4.8 the `Metadata` type synonym was defined as follows:

```
type Metadata = HashMap.Map String String
```

The metadata were just a flat list of *key – value* pairs.

In hakyll 4.8, metadata parsing was changed ([issue](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/issues/225), [commit](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/commit/e81468e0f64fdbe05794d5f8ccaebc00ee474ee2), [release anouncement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hakyll/M3SNUkH2zsQ/Ft43KrOsAwAJ)) to use YAML parser, to allow more complex metadata structure. Now, the type synonym is following:

```
type Metadata = Aeson.Object
```

This is the [`Object`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:Object) from [`aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) package – [`Data.Yaml`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml) library shares the types.

Unfortunately, handling the `Aeson.Object` is not as straightforward as the `Map` was. To learn how to use Aeson properly, you can read a [lengthy tutorial](https://artyom.me/aeson).

Luckily, Jasper provided us with a function [`lookupString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.8.3.1/docs/Hakyll-Core-Metadata.html#v:lookupString) which is almost a drop-in replacement of `HashMap.!`:

```
(!) :: Metadata -> String -> String
lookupString :: String -> Metadata -> Maybe String
```

Unwrapping the Maybe value, you will then get something like the following code:

```
directorizeDateAndAuthor :: Routes
directorizeDateAndAuthor = metadataRoute $ \md ->
  case lookupString "author" md of
      Just author ->
          gsubRoute "/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-" $ \s ->
              replaceAll "-" (const "/") s ++ author ++ "/"
      Nothing -> error "The author metadata field is missing."
```